# LinqToXml Construct a class object with a xml file

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I would like to build an object with a xml source file.
i need to get the 'Site' element which matches with a specific "SiteName".
And build my object (LocalisationInfo class) with all the elements in the 'Site' element.
Thanks you.

here is what the xml file looks like:

```
<Sites>
   <Site>
      <longitude>1.555</longitude>
      <latitude>4.488003</latitude>
      <SiteName>Aix en Provence</SiteName>
      <FullAdresse>adresse here</FullAdresse>
      <NomResponsable>martin Véronique</NomResponsable>
      <AdressePostale>260 rue Louis de Broglie</AdressePostale>
      <CodePostal>13799</CodePostal>
      <Ville>Aix-En-Provence</Ville>
      <Pays>France</Pays>
   </Site>

   <Site>
   </Site>
   <Site>
   </Site>
```

here is my CODE which is not working...

```
  XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Resources/Sites.xml");

            var lesite = from d in xdoc.Descendants("Site")           
                         where d.Element("SiteName").Value == sitelocalisation
                         select new LocalisationInfo
            {
                TelSecouriste = d.Element("TelSecouriste").Value,
                Longitude = d.Element("longitude").Value,
                Latitude = d.Element("latitude").Value,
                Pays = d.Element("Pays").Value,
                CodePostal = d.Element("CodePostal").Value,
                Ville = d.Element("Ville").Value,
                Standard = d.Element("Standard").Value,
                SiteName = d.Element("SiteName").Value,
                AdressePostale = d.Element("AdressePostale").Value,

            };
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Do you have exception?

Answer (score 1):

I can assume that you have some `Site` element without `SiteName` child, or there is some other element missing on matched site. Thus you are accessing `Value` property of elements, then you will receive `NullReferenceException` if some element was not found. Use casting to string instead - that will return `null` instead of raising exception:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load("Resources/Sites.xml");

var lesite = from s in xdoc.Root.Elements("Site")           
             where (string)s.Element("SiteName") == sitelocalisation
             select new LocalisationInfo {
                TelSecouriste = (string)s.Element("TelSecouriste"),
                Longitude = (string)s.Element("longitude"),
                Latitude = (string)s.Element("latitude"),
                Pays = (string)s.Element("Pays"),
                CodePostal = (string)s.Element("CodePostal"),
                Ville = (string)s.Element("Ville"),
                Standard = (string)s.Element("Standard"),
                SiteName = (string)s.Element("SiteName"),
                AdressePostale = (string)s.Element("AdressePostale"),
            };
```

Keep in mind that this query will return sequence of matched sites. So, if you need only first one then use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
 var result = lesite.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: @Alex thanks! it will be funny if error looks like `FileNotFoundException` :)

Comment: You can just feel it will be that :D

Comment: Awesome !! It works ! The "firstordefault" was necessary...I guess the binding with my UI object couldn't work because the object i binded was an IEnumerable. But now all is fine :) Thks very much